# Achieving Fail-safe behaviour in flow

Tags: java, mule, mule-flow

I am trying to create a fail-safe scenario in my flow.

My flow looks like below. It involves some sub-flows which intern have call to web-services.
In any scenario if one of the web-service is not available the connection-refused exception is thrown and the whole processing stops.

Instead I want a fail-safe scenario where the flow should continue with the next sub-flows even if the current out-bound call fails.

Is there any message processor or flow-control processor that could help acheive this behaviour in Mule.

Given below is my abstract flow

```
<flow name="main_flow" >
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="subflow_1" />
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="subflow_2" />
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="subflow_3" />
    ....
    ....

</flow>

<sub-flow name="subflow_1">
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    ....
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="subflow_2">
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    ....
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="subflow_3">
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    ....
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: Are the sub-flow interactions dependent on each other? If not, you could parallelize them and each would die individually.

Comment: They are kind of dependant. In each sub-flow I need to extract some data from teh web-service response and add it to the input paylaod. Then this becomes the paylaod for the next sub-flow.

Comment: As you said, result of one sub-flow becomes payload for another sub-flow, then it won't make much sense to call 2nd sub-flow w/o receiving response from first.

Comment: @Learner is right: if the sub-flow interactions are dependent then why bother continuing the main flow if you can't fetch the data you need to proceed?

Comment: As I said its a kind of enrichment without using the enricher directly. Because the enrichment is based on some logic.  Its like The input is preserved. in each subflow a request is created from the payload which is suitable for the web-service call. Then from the response required data is extracted and enriched into the preserved input payload. Then this enriched paylaod is set as Paylaod to the next part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive the fail-safe behaviour with the flows.

```
<flow name="main_flow" >
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="flow_1" />
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="flow_2" />
    ....
    ....
    <flow-ref  name="flow_3" />
    ....
    ....

</flow>

<flow name="flow_1" processingStrategy="synchronous" >
    ....
    ....
    <out-bound call to web-service />
    ....
    <catch-exception-strategy >
      .... Your FailSafe code to recover. Also you will have the exception here.
     </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

This way you can schieve the fail safe behaviour using the flows.

Happy Coding   :)

Answer (score 1):

One hack could be to store the payload in a variable, have a `<catch-exception-strategy>` block which will catch your web-service invoke exception, use `<set-payload>` to overwrite the current payload and then call `sub-flow2` manually from `catch-exception` flow of `sub-flow1`

Comment: This solution I have already tried. But it is becoing more cumbersome. That is why looking if Mule has any such processors that can help.

Comment: Also sub-flow doesn't have its own exception strategy.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to use private flows.

Answer (score 1):

For each web-service call, use a [`first-successful`](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-FirstSuccessful) router, having your web-service call as the first child and the fall-back mechanism as the second one.

Comment: But the processing after the web-service call in the sub-flow is not required if the web-service call fails. In this case my flow  should jump from the web-service call end-point(which failed) to my main flow which then proceeds to the remaining flows. But how can I use first-successful for this.

Comment: If the webservice call fails, the rest of the sub-flow will not be executed. Instead, the second message processor in `first-successful` will kick-in, allowing you to provide default/fake/null whatever data in case the call fails.

Comment: I am able to do it.   <first-successful> 
   <flow-ref name="SubFlow_1"></flow-ref>
   <set-payload value="#[flowVars['preSubFlowPayload']]"></set-payload>  
  </first-successful>

Comment: I have an issue with this approach. When the sub-flow failes using first-successful I am moving onto the next step. But before that I need to do some thing as per the Exception. But I am not able to get hold of the Exception. Any idea how I can get the exceptionPaylaod.